# Calling HTTP endpoints via On-premises data gateway

Tags: rest, api, on-premise-data-gateway, service-endpoint

I have a requirement to get information from an old legacy system thats on premise.
If they have an API that is exposed can I use data gateway and a custom connector?
I need to use Power Automate to connect to the local API via a data gateway to get the data.
Can i create a custom connector using the local api exposed on the on premise server?
What are my options?
Thanks in Advance